# Using same LitElement multiple times in same page

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, lit-element, lit-html

Created web component using `LitElement`. I am using this component multiple times in the same page.

[image: click here]

I want to trigger one event only when my component is rendering first time on page.

Comment: It can be more helpful to add the code snippet using the editor rather than an image. Additionally, can you provide code for the attempts you have made so far?

Comment: `connectedcallback` triggers only once. ( i.e first time it connects ). Are you looking for `firstupdated`?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *"first time on page"*?

If you want the first time any instance renders in the current loaded page set `window.someProperty` before firing your event and then check it before firing the event again. Anything on `window` is cleared when the user navigates between pages, but if you're running an SPA (which Lit is particularly well suited to) that might not happen for a while.

If you want to do something the first time the element is *loaded* you can add the flag to the module that holds the element.

If you want each element to fire an event as it initially renders you can use `firstUpdated`.

If you want the first element somewhere in the document to fire an event then that's harder, as web components are all about isolated functionality - they aren't aware of other instances on the same page. Your best bet is to either:

- Add a parent component that picks up events from all the sub-components and only does something the first time it gets one.
- Add an index property that you increment for each instance and only have the event fire when it is `0`.